# Difference in creating triggers on views in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012.

The view definition is:

```
create view dbo.emp
as
   select 
       e.eid, e.enm, p.fnm, p.lnm 
   from 
       employee e 
   inner join 
       person p on e.eid = p.id
go
```

The first trigger definition is:

```
CREATE trigger emptrgg on emp
instead of insert 
as
begin 
    insert into person(id, fnm, lnm)
       select 
           id, fnm, lnm 
       from inserted

    insert into employee(eid, enm)
       select 
           eid, enm 
       from inserted
end
```

The trigger #2 (same as trigger #1, but the values are inserted through parameters)

```
CREATE TRIGGER emptrgg
ON emp
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @ID INT, @FName NVARCHAR(25), @LName NVARCHAR(25), @PID INT,
@EmNum NVARCHAR(15)

     SELECT @ID = eid, @FName =fnm, @LName = lnm
     FROM inserted

     INSERT INTO Person(Id, fnm, lnm)
     VALUES(@ID, @FName, @LName)

     INSERT INTO Employee(eid, enm)
     VALUES(@PID, @ENum)
 end
```

Which of the above is efficient or performance good?

I aint able to findout,could you help me with this?

regards,
Chio.

Comment: Trigger 2 won't work correctly, if you insert more than single record into view. Looking at style, I would say that you have copypasted from many sources ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your trigger #2 has a **MAJOR** flaw in that you assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case.

The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows.

Which of those 25 rows will your code select here??

```
SELECT @ID = eid, @FName = fnm, @LName = lnm 
FROM inserted
```

It's non-deterministic - you'll get one arbitrary row and ignore all 24 others.

Use trigger #1 **only!** It uses the proper, set-based approach to handle multiple inserted rows at once. And since it's set-based, it's also pretty much optimal for performance.